# Why `time_range` doesn't work in request to Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I try to get some data from Facebook Marketing API. The result I get are generally correct but I have problem with data. It seems like parametr `time_range` doesn't work.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/act_<MY_ACT>/ads?fields=name,adcreatives{object_story_id},insights{spend,unique_clicks},effective_status&params=time_range={%22since%22:%222016-11-15%22,%22until%22:%222016-11-17%22}&limit=2000&access_token=<MY_TOKEN>
```

Result:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "xx",
         "adcreatives": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "id": "xx"
               }
            ]
         },
         "effective_status": "DISAPPROVED",
         "id": "xx"
      },
      {
         "name": "xx",
         "adcreatives": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "id": "xx"
               }
            ]
         },
         "insights": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "spend": xx,
                  "unique_clicks": "34",
                  "date_start": "2016-10-19",
                  "date_stop": "2016-11-17"
               }
            ],
            "paging": {
               "cursors": {
                  "before": "MAZDZD",
                  "after": "MAZDZD"
               }
            }
         },
         "effective_status": "CAMPAIGN_PAUSED",
         "id": "xx"
      },...}
```

I tried encode it, write in different way, but each time the results are from the last month, so date_start is 2016-10-19 and date_stop is 2016-10-17, not from range I put as parametr in query. How can I fix it?

Edit:
I also tried instead of `&params=time_range={%22since%22:%222016-11-15%22,%22until%22:%222016-11-17%22}` something like `&date_preset=yesterday` (yesterday or other correct value listed in documentation) but still I get exact same dates...

Comment: Ok found partial solution. Value of parameter `date_preset` should be place after `insights.`, so something like this works: `/ads?fields=name,adcreatives{object_story_id},insights.date_preset(yesterday){spend,unique_clicks},effective_status&limit=2000`. But still I don't know how to get values from undefined time range...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to get insights within certain time_range:

```
/act_<ACCT_ID>/insights?level=ad&time_range={"since":"2016-11-15","until":"2016-11-17"}
```